# list problemo in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When I run this code it says that there is error in two lines that are commented.

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys

def birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar):
    j=1

    for f in range(0,n):      
            b=f+1
         #   if ar[f]<ar[b]:
                if f==n:
                    break
                else:
                        m=ar[b]
                        for k in range(0,n):
                            if m==ar[k]:
                                j=j+1

    return j    

n = int(input().strip())
ar = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
  #  print(birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar))
```

> Error (stderr) Traceback (most recent call last): File "solution.py", line 23, in  print(birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar)) File "solution.py", line 10, in birthdayCakeCandles if ar[f]

Comment: If you're getting error messages you must provide them. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Error (stderr)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar))
  File "solution.py", line 10, in birthdayCakeCandles
    if ar[f]<ar[b]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What isn't clear? The error message is straightforward: your list index is out of range.

Comment: First off, when you are doing a coding challenge and can't figure out what to do, that might be a sign that you should learn more, rather than just paste the issue into stack overflow. Also, did you actually write the code above? Because it doesn't sound like you have any clue how it works. Also, add the sample input.

Comment: yes, i wrote it, i used c++ for a little bit, now python cause its easier, if you tell me how to correct the mistake, ill go over it again and learn from it, gain experience. im pretty sure i wrote something dumb cause im new, so just tell me whats not right in the lists, arrays.correct, this is a hackerrank easiest challenge about cakes, but as you can see i didnt ask for the whole solution

Comment: What is the input and desired output?

Comment: input for n is 4     for rn is [1, 2, 3, 3]    output 2

Comment: Colleen is turning [n] years old! Therefore, she has [n] candles of various heights on her cake, and candle [ i ] has height[i]  . Because the taller candles tower over the shorter ones, Colleen can only blow out the tallest candles.

Given the for each individual candle, find and print the number of candles she can successfully blow out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for f in range(0,n):      
    b=f+1
    if ar[f]<ar[b]:
```

Here you referenced an index of a list greater than the length of the list, which is why you got the error. n is the length of the list, so when you add 1 to it for b, it will be an index that doesn't exist. It looks like you might have been aware of this issue happening with this code block:

```
if f==n:
    break
```

However, the program already ran into the error before it got to that point. My solution is to replace n with n-1 in the code above. I am not sure if that fulfills the challenge, I need to read it more thoroughly. Here is what my code looks like. I also got rid of the second code block above because it doesn't do anything.

```
def birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar):
    j=1
    for f in range(0,n-1):      
        b=f+1
        #if one element is less than the following
        if ar[f]<ar[b]:
            #count the number of elements equal to the following element, add to j
            m=ar[b]
            for k in range(0,n):
                if m==ar[k]:
                j+=1
    return j    

 n = int(input().strip())
 ar = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
 print(birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar))
```

I also replace j=j+1 with j+=1. Also, the second for loop can be replaced with a list comprehension, but I don't know if you know about them so I left it as it is.

It looks like [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/birthday-cake-candles/problem) is the challenge you are trying to do, in which case you misunderstood it, and the code above will not work for it. Read it through again and read the example. It is a lot simpler than you think.

Comment: thank you, i forgot actually knew that counting starts from 0 but.... couldnt notice, thank you ao much

Answer (score -1):

```
            else:
                    m=ar[b]
                    for k in range(0,n):
                        if m==ar[k]:
                            j=j+1
```

Is indented incorrectly. It should be:

```
            else:
                m=ar[b]
                for k in range(0,n):
                    if m==ar[k]:
                        j=j+1
```

Also,

```
for f in range(0,n):      
        b=f+1
     #   if ar[f]<ar[b]: <-- Your commented out line used to create a new block
            if f==n:   # <-- This line is incorrectly indented as a result
                break (and all lines after)
            else:
                m=ar[b]  # I moved this back in, not a syntax error, but is incorrect. 
                for k in range(0,n):
                    if m==ar[k]:
                        j=j+1
```

Comment: That isn't the issue. Read the error message.

Comment: It is part of a larger issue though. Your indenting is incorrect in multiple places. See my original post.

Comment: The indentation is not the issue. He just messed up the formatting when he pasted it here. If the indentation was the issue, that would be the error.

Comment: It is the issue. When you comment a line out that used to create a new code block, your subsequent code block is mis-indented. It has nothing to do with his copy paste.

Comment: He put the error message in the comment. Nowhere in it does it mention "IndentationError: unexpected indent". It is an index error. That is how you know the indentation was right when he wrote it.

Comment: Yeah, that is why you have to reformat it. Copy and pasting messes up the  format. That is still not the issue.

Comment: Ok, I understand. OP should update his post to reflect this.